# insert a null value in a foreign key column using a merge statement oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, merge

I have a table `imp` described as imp(ID, col1, col2, col3) and a second table `soc` (ID, colSoc1, colSoc2, colSoc3). The ColSoc3 is a foreign key to another table .
I've implemented the following request to merge the two tables :

```
 MERGE INTO soc tb
    USING (
              SELECT ID,
                     col1,
                     col2,
                     CASE
                      WHEN col3= NULL THEN
                          NULL
                      ELSE
                          col3
                      END AS col3
              from imp ) req on ( tb.ID=req.ID)
   when matched then 
     update set tb.colSoc1=req.col1, tb.colSoc2=req.col2, tb.colSoc3=req.col3
   when not matched then  
    insert (ID, colSoc1, colSoc2, colSoc3) 
   values (req.ID, req.col1, req.col2, req.col3);
```

The problem I have is when the col3 value is NULL nothing is inserted in the `soc` table.
How can I force insertion of `col3` into `Colsoc3` even if it has null value?

the ddl for soc is as below :

```
  CREATE TABLE "OWNER"."soc" 
   (    
    "ID" VARCHAR2(17 CHAR) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    "socCol1" VARCHAR2(17 CHAR), 
    "socCol2" VARCHAR2(17 CHAR),  
    "socCol3" VARCHAR2(17 CHAR),  
     CONSTRAINT "Soc_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("ID")
  USING INDEX PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 COMPUTE STATISTICS 
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "DATA0001"  ENABLE, 
     CONSTRAINT "Soc_FK1" FOREIGN KEY ("socCol3")
      REFERENCES "OWNER"."socParent" ("ID_parent") ENABLE
   ) SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE 
  PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 
 NOCOMPRESS NOLOGGING
  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
  TABLESPACE "DATA0001" ;
```

what let me think that the null foreign key is the problem is I tried not to insert col3 and it worked and then I used the request below to see what are the lines with parent key not found and the result all have null value for col3

```
select * from imp where col3 not in ( select ID_parent from socParent);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `WHEN col3= NULL THEN` is never true; maybe you meant `WHEN col3 IS NULL THEN`, but what's the point of that case expression?

Comment: Your CASE statement is wrong. NULL never equals anything, you should be testing `when col3 is null`. Except you're only assigning NULL anyway, so what's the point? This flows into your actual problem: how to force insertion of col3 into Colsoc3 even if it has null value? If COL3 is null there's nothing to assign. Do you mean you want to apply a default value? It would help if you provide some sample rows for IMP and SOC, and showed us what outcome you want from the merge.

Comment: @AlexPoole I used WHEN col3= NULL THEN to avoid exception because it's a foreign key

Comment: @APC the point is that sometimes col3 is not null and sometimes is null but when I run my code (in a procedure) nothing is inserted because those null value erase an exception of type " parent key not found" so I want to force insertion of imp table even if there is some null value of column col3

Comment: If you got an exception without the case expression then you'll still get it with the case expression, as it isn't doing anything useful. But you haven't shown an exception - is that what you mean by 'nothing is inserted'? What you've shown [works](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=3540993fd6680217b2b838ebbdaa5808), so something is missing. Please add the table DDL and sample data to your question (vie [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/64337215/edit)).

Comment: for exemple imp has two lines the first  col3 = val3 not null : (1, 'val1', 'val2','val3'), the second line col3 is null ( 2, 'val11', 'val22', null), so I want to have the same lines in soc table as I suppose that those two lines does not exist in soc table to skip update clause.

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/64337215/edit) to add DDL and sample data. But why do you think the null value is causing the parent-key error, rather than one of the other `col3` values in the `imp` table? Have you verified that all of the non-null values do exist? [Foreign keys can be null](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/adfns/data-integrity.html#GUID-70F1D209-144D-4479-ABB8-559734B11E00).

Comment: One remark, from your DDL, you're using mixed case in the names of the columns and tables, so you need to use that in your sql (i.e. merge into "soc" .....)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried : WHEN col3 = 'null' instead of WHEN col3 is NULL and it works.